# Django Hide unavailable dates

Tags: django

I have a simple application to have an appointment with a doctor. I would like to have an appointment when the doctor is available and hide the occupation date in my form. **i would like to hide the unavailable slots from my view**

form:

```css
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('doctor', 'date', 'timeslot', 'patient_name')
```

model :

```css
from django.db import models
class Appointment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('doctor', 'date', 'timeslot')
    TIMESLOT_LIST = (
        (0, '09:00 – 09:30'),
        (1, '10:00 – 10:30'),
        (2, '11:00 – 11:30'),
        (3, '12:00 – 12:30'),
        (4, '13:00 – 13:30'),
        (5, '14:00 – 14:30'),
        (6, '15:00 – 15:30'),
        (7, '16:00 – 16:30'),
        (8, '17:00 – 17:30'),
    )
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    timeslot = models.IntegerField(choices=TIMESLOT_LIST)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}. Patient: {}'.format(self.date, self.time, self.doctor, self.patient_name)
    
    @property
    def time(self):
        return self.TIMESLOT_LIST[self.timeslot][1]


class Doctor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.specialty, self.short_name)

    @property
    def short_name(self):
        return '{} {}.{}.'.format(self.last_name.title(), self.first_name[0].upper(), self.middle_name[0].upper())
```

Comment: Please ask your question clearly. You just write the model and form code. Add your view's code and clearly state the problem

Comment: hi sorry i forgot to ask my question, i would like to hide the unavailable slots from my view

Comment: Please add your view's code. Show the result you get, and also show the expected result. Your question is still not clear.